# Downloading a PDF from server

Tags: php, html, pdf

I put the file "rodo.pdf" to my server in "img" folder.
Made the 664 permission on the file.
And using this code :

```
<p class="menu_up"> <a href="../img/rodo.pdf" title="Firma z RODO" class="amenu_up"  'id="menu_activ"';?>RODO</a></p>
```

I got 404 that file is not found on the server.

Link to my website is http://biurorachunkowepartner.pl/  On the left menu the link " RODO " is the one where it should start downloading a file.

Comment: This regular URL also says 404: http://biurorachunkowepartner.pl/img/rodo.pdf are you sure that file is in correct path?

Comment: It's spelled http://biurorachunkowepartner.pl/img/rodo.PDF - so either rename or link to the correctly spelled file. MOST Servers are case sensitive

Comment: Yeah i tried different paths.

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: without knowing your folder structure it is not possible to answer. in what folder is the html you show? and where is the img folder? For what you put there (../) it is one level up from where the html is. Is it correct?

Comment: @ŁukaszZ as @mplungjan said, change your code to ` <a href="../img/rodo.PDF" ` or rename your file extension to lowercase. It'll be fine.

Comment: Please delete the question